# Determinant of a tridiagonal matrix $A_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $a,b \in F$, $0 \leq n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $A_n = [a_{ij}] \in M_n(F)$.

> Define $$A_n=\begin{cases}
> a,&\text{if}\enspace j=i+1\\
> b,&\text{if}\enspace j=i-1 \\
> 0,&\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$

How can i establish the formula for the $\text{det}A_n$?